# How to rename multiple files with multiple letters and numbers combinations and sizes using bash or regex?

Tags: regex, bash, rename, filenames

I've been trying to rename a list of files by it's been quite difficult...
The 41 filenames are:

```
    BEIII_S29_pear_derep.fasta
    BEII_S15_pear_derep.fasta
    BEI_S1_pear_derep.fasta 
    MB211III_S30_pear_derep.fasta
    MB211II_S16_pear_derep.fasta
    MB211I_S2_pear_derep.fasta
    ...
```

and I need to rename to:

```
    BEIII.fas
    BEII.fas
    BEI.fas
    MB211III.fas
    MB211II.fas
    MB211I.fas
```

I tryed using for loop:

```
    for i in *_S[0-9]{1,2}_pear_derep.fasta; do newfile="$(basename $i _S[0-9]{1,2}_pear_derep.fasta)"; echo $newfile; cp ${newfile}_S[0-9]{1,2}_pear_derep.fasta ${newfile}.fas; done;
```

It didn't work, then

```
    rename 's/([A-Z]*[0-9]*[I]{1,4})_[A-Z][0-9]_[a-z]_[a-z]{1,5}(\.fasta).*/$1$2/g' *
```

It didn't work
then

```
    for file in *.fas; do newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed -re 's/S_[0-9][0-9](\.)/\./g') mv -v $file $newfile; done;
```

None of them worked.
The thing here is that I have to use a regex to KEEP a variable beggining, which varys between

```
    [A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[I]{1,3}
```

then everything else is excluded

```
    S[0-9]{1,2}_[a-z]{4}_[a-z]{5} and then the extension .fasta to .fas
```

Could someone help me please?
Thank you Guys

Comment: What is `echo "$$i"` supposed to mean? The iteration variable is `$file`, not `$i`. Why do you have two `$$`?

Comment: In your `rename` example, why do you have `S1` at the beginning of the replacement? Is that supposed to be `$1`?

Comment: sorry sorry, It was writing error, it's corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that `*\.fasta` targets every file you need. Make sure that you echo the `mv` command or create a copy of the directory and try it there first.

```
for i in *\.fasta; do 
    mv $i ${i/_*/}.fas;
done
```

The substitution `${i/_*/}` removes everything after the first `_`.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` in wildcards.

Comment: I always escape the `.` in everything that looks like a regex just to be sure (and to be clear). I already had my first root screw-up and don't intend to make another one :p

Comment: `mv -- "$i" "${i/_*/}.fas"` is better if safety and stability is your concern

Comment: This answer assumes that you don't need to match things like `III` specifically in the first component of the name, as the regexp attempts to do.

Answer (score 1):

The regexp in your `rename` attempt is missing a bunch of quantifiers. Also, it doesn't change the extension from `.fasta` to `.fas`. You should also anchor it to the beginning and end of the filename. There's no need for the `g` modifier, since you're only doing one replacement per name.

```
rename 's/^([A-Z]*[0-9]*I{1,4})_[A-Z][0-9]*_[a-z]*_[a-z]{1,5}\.fasta$/$1.fas/' *
```

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I just started to learn those more complex regex, your comment helped a lot!!!